# SQL Server, how to display (square) ^2 as in column heading?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Please guide me how to display m2 (m with 2 as square small on top of m) in column heading ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[]` to enclose the name:

```
select  1 as [^2]
```

Or if you mean a small 2 instead, use Unicode `00B2`:

```
select  1 as [m²]
```

You can enter Unicode `00B2` with keystroke `Alt+0178`.  Keep `alt` pressed while you type `0178`.

Answer (score 1):

As per SQL Server standards:

Column names should contain only letters and numbers. No special characters, underscores or spaces should be used.